# Compressing axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot

[image: plot]

```
p1<-ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-10, 30),y=c(0,250)), aes(x,y))
p1<-p1 +stat_function(fun=function(x)12+180/(1+exp(-.759*(x-7.69))),size = 2,color="yellow")+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 250))+geom_abline(intercept = 44, slope = 0,lty=2)+scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-5,25))+ geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=80))
print(p1)
```

I am trying to change the axes so that the part above dotted line gets "squashed" and the part below dotted line) gets expanded (but without changing the axes).  In other words, I want the scale of the lower part of the plot to be wider and the scale of the upper part to be narrower so that the part of the plot below the dotted line is more prominently displayed.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: where do i make this transformation?

Comment: I'll delete. My offhand comment. I don't see a way to do it properly. I was thinking you could scale the lower porting to [0-1] and the upper portion to [1-200] but my suggestion doesn't do that. Maybe take log(y/44)?

Answer (score 4):

I hope I had understood correctly what you need.

I don't know what @42- comment was, but I think a coord transformation is definitely the way to go.

```r
library(scales)
magnify_trans <- function(intercept, reducer) {

    trans <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
        sapply(x, function(x) {
            if (x < i) x
            else x / r + i
        })
    }

    inv <- function(x, i = intercept, r = reducer) {
        sapply(x, function(x) {
            if(!is.na(x)) {
                if (x < i) x
                else (x - i) * r
            }
        })
    }

    trans_new(name = 'custom',
              transform = trans,
              inverse = inv
              )
}
```

We defined a `transformation` that divides the values above `intercept` by the `reducer` arg.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-10, 30), y = c(0, 250)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) 12 + 180 / (1 + exp(-.759*(x - 7.69))),
                  size = 2,
                  color = "yellow") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 250))+
    geom_abline(intercept = 44, slope = 0, lty = 2)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 25)) +
    coord_trans(y = magnify_trans(intercept = 44, reducer = 20))
```

[image]

The same transformation can be used on the x axis, if that's what you want:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-10, 30), y = c(0, 250)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) 12 + 180 / (1 + exp(-.759 * (x - 7.69))),
                  size = 2,
                  color = "yellow") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 250))+
    geom_abline(intercept = 44, slope = 0, lty = 2)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 25)) +
    coord_trans(x = magnify_trans(intercept = 5.675, reducer = 20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a generalisation for compressing outside an interval. I hope it is useful to someone.

```
magnify_trans <- function(interval_low = 0, interval_high = 7,  reducer = 20) {

    trans <- function(x, i_low = interval_low, i_high = interval_high, r = reducer) 
        sapply(x, function(x) {
            if(x >= i_low & x <= i_high ) x
            else if(x < i_low) x / r + i_low
            else (x - i_high) / r + i_high
        })

    inv <- function(x, i_low = interval_low, i_high = interval_high, r = reducer) 
        sapply(x, function(x) {
            if(x >= i_low & x <= i_high ) x
            else if(x < i_low) (x - i_low) * r
            else ((x - i_high) * r) + i_high
        })

    trans_new(name = 'custom',  transform = trans,inverse = inv )
}
```