# ggplot sec_axis does not work with transformations that raise the axis to a power in version 3.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` to plot log2 transformed data but would also like to show the untransformed equivalent values as a secondary axis. Since the data is already log2 transformed, I should be able to reverse the transformation by raising 2 to that power (`~2^.`). This worked very nicely in version 3.0.0, but after upgrading to 3.1.0, this code produces no errors but makes a secondary axis that doesn't make any sense:

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=(~2^.)))
```

[image]

Secondary axes work normally with other formulas (`~.`, `~. + 10`, and `~ . * 10` all work as expected), only `~2^.` is giving me any problems.

---

I'm pretty sure this is related to upgrading to version 3.1 since in according to the [release notes](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.1.0), there was a change related specifically to using `sec_axis` with log transformed data, but I can't figure out what was changed and why it's behaving the way is does now. Does anyone know more about this, or have any idea of a workaround other than downgrading to 3.0?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.0 crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.7.7      R6_2.3.0         grid_3.5.1      
 [8] plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.3.0.1    lazyeval_0.2.1  
[15] rstudioapi_0.7   bindrcpp_0.2.2   labeling_0.3     tools_3.5.1      glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.2.5      munsell_0.5.0   
[22] yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.2  colorspace_1.3-2 tidyselect_0.2.5 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2
```

Comment: Maybe related issue: [Ticks misaligned for sec_axis with some scale transformations and data in 3.1.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2978).

Comment: This has been confirmed as a bug. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53150998/9598813 for a workaround.

Comment: @divibisan the example that I linked actually *does* involve rescaling the values. I suggest you take another look at it, as it contains what you need, but I can also add a quick solution for you.

Comment: @MarcusCampbell Ah, I see, just figured it out! The key is scaling the `breaks` and the `labels` differently.

Comment: Great - I'm glad I could help you! This is a frustrating problem, and I'm sure the ggplot team is working hard at fixing it as we speak. Hopefully we see a fix soon!

Comment: @MarcusCampbell It looks like they're working on it, but for now your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is currently a bug with `ggplot2` version 3.1.0.

For now, a simple workaround for your case is to just pre-define your desired break positions, where they would occur in *untransformed space*, and then perform the desired transform. Using the `breaks` argument is necessary to get the positioning correct.

**Try this code:**

```
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(7)
# Create some log (base 2) transformed data
df = data.frame(x = log2(runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)),
                y = log2(runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)))

# A vector of your desired break positions in untransformed space
sec_breaks <- c(0.4,0.5,1,2,4,8,10)
# Transform break positions
scaled_breaks <- log2(sec_breaks)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = (~.),
                                         breaks = scaled_breaks,
                                         labels = sprintf("%.1f", sec_breaks)))
```

**Which gives this plot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed. In the newest version of ggplot (3.2.1), the following code now correctly renders the secondary axis:

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=(~2^.)))
```

[image]